# Slow abs() function in Python. Explain?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was bored, and I decided to come up with a method to calculate pi. I implemented it, and it ran well. I wanted to optimize it, so I ran the profiler. It took about 26 seconds. I discovered that the `abs()` function took up a lot of lag, so I came up with a way to avoid the `abs()` function. After that, I could run it in 8 seconds! Can someone explain to me why the `abs()` function was taking so long?

Here is the code without `abs()`:

```
def picalc(radius = 10000000):
    total = 0
    x = 0
    y = radius
    for i in range(radius + 1):
        x1 = i
        y1 = (radius ** 2 - x1 ** 2) ** 0.5
        total += ((x1 - x) ** 2 + (y1 - y) ** 2) ** 0.5
        x = x1
        y = y1
    print(total / (radius / 2))
import profile
profile.run('picalc()')
```

If I change the line `total += ((x1 - x) ** 2 + (y1 - y) ** 2) ** 0.5` to `total += (abs(x1 - x) ** 2 + abs(y1 - y) ** 2) ** 0.5`, the operation runs MUCH slower.

EDIT: I know that the negatives cancel when squaring. That was a mistake I made.

EDIT x2: I tried substituting `total += ((x1 - x) ** 2 + (y1 - y) ** 2) ** 0.5` with `total += math.hypot(x1 - x, y1 - y)`, but the profiler tells me it took 10 seconds longer! I read the docs and they said that the math library contains thin wrappers to the C math library (at least in IDLE). How can C be slower than Python in this case?

Comment: There's no reason to call `abs()` before squaring something since the negatives cancel as in `-2*-2 == +4 == 2*2`.  The time doesn't sound so bad. There are some more pi examples  [here](http://blog.sunshineonacloudy.net/2015/06/introduction-to-apache-spark_64.html) in a blog article I wrote.

Comment: Aside: performance-wise in pure Python, you're unlikely to beat [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.hypot), which in your case would look like `hypot(x1-x, y1-y)`.

Comment: @DSM You know what's wierd? Using `math.hypot()`, the operation takes 10 more seconds!!! Somehow, I've beaten `math.hypot()` in performance...

Answer (score 7):

First of all: the `abs()` calls are entirely redundant if you are squaring the result *anyway*.

Next, you may be reading the `profile` output wrong; don't mistake the cumulative times with the time spent only on the function call itself; you are calling `abs()` many many times so the accumulated time will raise rapidly.

Moreover, profiling adds a lot of overhead to the interpreter. Use the `timeit` module to compare the performance between approaches, it gives you overall performance metrics so you can compare apples with apples.

It is not that the `abs()` function is slow; it is *calling any function* that is 'slow'. Looking up the global name is slower than looking up locals, and then you need to push the current frame on the stack, execute the function, then pop the frame from the stack again.

You can alleviate one of those pain points by making `abs()` a local name outside the loop:

```
_abs = abs
for i in range(radius + 1):
    # ...
    total += (_abs(x1 - x) ** 2 + _abs(y1 - y) ** 2) ** 0.5
```

Not that `abs()` really is taking such a huge toll on your performance, really, not when you time your functions properly. Using a radius of 1000 to make 100 repeats practical, `timeit` comparisons give me:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def picalc(radius = 10000000):
...     total = 0
...     x = 0
...     y = radius
...     for i in range(radius + 1):
...         x1 = i
...         y1 = (radius ** 2 - x1 ** 2) ** 0.5
...         total += ((x1 - x) ** 2 + (y1 - y) ** 2) ** 0.5
...         x = x1
...         y = y1
... 
>>> def picalc_abs(radius = 10000000):
...     total = 0
...     x = 0
...     y = radius
...     for i in range(radius + 1):
...         x1 = i
...         y1 = (radius ** 2 - x1 ** 2) ** 0.5
...         total += (abs(x1 - x) ** 2 + abs(y1 - y) ** 2) ** 0.5
...         x = x1
...         y = y1
... 
>>> def picalc_abs_local(radius = 10000000):
...     total = 0
...     x = 0
...     y = radius
...     _abs = abs
...     for i in range(radius + 1):
...         x1 = i
...         y1 = (radius ** 2 - x1 ** 2) ** 0.5
...         total += (_abs(x1 - x) ** 2 + _abs(y1 - y) ** 2) ** 0.5
...         x = x1
...         y = y1
... 
>>> timeit('picalc(1000)', 'from __main__ import picalc', number=100)
0.13862298399908468
>>> timeit('picalc(1000)', 'from __main__ import picalc_abs as picalc', number=100)
0.14540845900774002
>>> timeit('picalc(1000)', 'from __main__ import picalc_abs_local as picalc', number=100)
0.13702849800756667
```

Notice how there is *very little difference* between the three approaches now.

Comment: Personally, rather than `_abs = abs`, I generally prefer the approach of binding them in the function definition: `def picalc_abs_local(radius = 10000000, abs=abs):`  It's an after-the-fact optimization that can be applied to every non-changing lookup inside loops without altering any of the _real_ code.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin: I do often use function default arguments to create locals from globals like that, but I would *definitely* use a leading underscore even then, to make it a) clear the argument is not needed when calling the function and b) that inside the function body you are working with a local now, replacing the global later on will not affect that binding.

Comment: I suppose opinions vary, but if I see _abs(x), I'm going to think it's some kind of special function, not the built-in, and if I see abs=abs in the signature, I'm going to realize it's the built-in, because using that name for something else would just be really confusing...